# Upload a file from your code base to S3 as part of Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I want to create an S3 bucket and put a file into it before rest of the application starts. The file I want to upload exists in the Project and I thought directly uploading it as part of Lambda execution will work fine but seems that would not work as expected.

What is the recommended way in this scenario?

Comment: If i'm understanding you correctly this is what you're looking for? https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-cli-package.html

Comment: That command seems to be for Lamda/API Gareway artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a template that will help to start,

https://s3.amazonaws.com/htmlformation/s3template.yml

```
Parameters:
  url:
    Type: String
    Description: Link to HTML to pull
    Default: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pmcdowell-okta/cloudformation-deploy-html/master/html/index.html



Outputs:
      bucketURL:
        Value:
          Fn::Join:
            - ''
            - - 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/'
              - Fn::GetAtt:
                    - DeploymentCustomResource
              - '/index.html'

    DeploymentCustomResource:
        Type: Custom::deploytos3
        Properties:
          ServiceToken: !GetAtt deploytos3.Arn
          url: !Ref url
          bucketname: !Ref bucketname
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I am just wondering if it could take a local file checked in with the code.

Comment: You cannot copy from local computer to CloudFormation. Reason is, CloudFormation template runs on remote systems and remote systems does not know how to contact your local machine. You need to upload it to a version control or  HTTP/s URL to pull the file and put it in the bucket. Make your CloudFormation so that is not machine aware / local aware and only cloud aware, that is a good practice too.